Ubuntu with two static VLANS and ethernet Internet. Can't ping VLANs
Have Unbuntu with 4-6 ethernets ports. I have a router setup with VLANs trunked to switch.
Two VLANS (10 & 100) are hooked to Ubuntu. I can ping all VLANS (10,100, 22, 30, 101). No problem. Now I hook up Internet (DHCP) to Ethernet port on Ubuntu, and now can't ping any VLANS, even the ones plugged into Ubuntu (gateways 192.168.1.1 for VLAN10, 192.168.100.1 gateway for VLAN100). The internet has IP of 192.168.0.1 as gateway, with IP of 192.168.0.106.
I think I have to use a iptable maybe to fix this in Ubunutu?  My thought would be if I ping 192.168.100.1 that Internet connection will not resolve this, and other VLAN will pass it through the switch and router. But no.. ?? Not with internet on ethernet port. When disconnect Internet, can ping all VLANS no problem.
Any thoughts on how to address with WITH internet?

Ubuntu22.04 not server.

Can you include your configuration?  You may need to start statically defining routes in your environment, and it'll be useful to know what actual configuration you've set on your interfaces, VLANs, etc. and how.

If the addition of a DHCP route is the culprit - it probably has something to with the the routing table.  Take a look at the routing table before and after the addition of the DHCP link (ip route).  DHCP will set a new default route - so, you could have two default routes set after the DHCP client has picked up the link.
The Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control may be helpful as well (https://lartc.org/howto/)
